# How can I maintain hover in vertical css dropdown menu?

Tags: css

Ah ha, I've discovered the problem. Html code further down was overlapping my menu. Z-index and few tweaks solved it. See changes below. No doubt a css wizard can make further improvements, but this has put me on the road.

Many thanks to all for input.

---

As intended, drop down selections appears on the right of my vertical menu upon mouse hover. But they disappear as soon as I move the mouse to the right to select. Can some kind soul point out what changes I need to make in the code below to have a fully functional vertical drop down menu?

Many thanks,

LRP

My css code:

```
div.tools {
   padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

div.tools ul  {
   margin:  0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 9em;
   background: #00ab6f;
   color: white;
   border-radius: .3em;
}

.tools li {
   position: relative;
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
}

.tools ul ul {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 9em;
   display: none;
}

.tools ul li a {
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: white;
   padding: .6em;
   border-radius: .3em;
}

.tools ul li:hover ul {
   display: block;
   z-index: 3;
}


.tools ul li ul li:hover {
    display: block;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Comment: @Loyd post your HTML and CSS code

Comment: I created a jsfiddle based on your css and it seems to work as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/8bm71md5/

Answer (score 0):

Note that I've found solution. See edits above.

Thanks to all.

LRP